# JavaScript - convert timestamp to date, then convert back to timestamp

Tags: javascript, mysql, date, utc

My server app returns a timestamp string which is in UTC.

Now I want to convert it to a date object to get the local datetime, then convert that date object back to timestamp to get the local timestamp.

This doesn't seem to work as both strings outputted are identical

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(timestamp));
var date = new Date(timestamp*1000).getTime();
console.log(JSON.stringify(date));
```

How do I work this out?

Comment: var date = new Date(timestamp*1000).getTime() will give you in millisecond. You just remove the getTime() will give you date object

Comment: obviously it will print identical... you are printing the same thing again!!
when you say "local timestamp" do you mean the client side time?

Comment: Can you provide me a sample timestamp value that you are getting from the server

Comment: Sample timestamp `1470621520` and yes I mean client side time i.e. what appears on their os' screen.

Comment: do you need the current time? Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new instance of Date using the timestamp (which I assume is already a well-formatted date-object). Your code will look like this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(timestamp));
var date = new Date(timestamp);
console.log(JSON.stringify(date));
```

Give it a try and let me know if the output is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what u need.
You need to take the current time, convert it and send it back to the server in the format u need.

```
var timestamp = 1470621520;
console.log(JSON.stringify(timestamp));
var date = Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
console.log(JSON.stringify(date));
```

**EDIT** As per the comments, for converting the UTC time to local timezone you could do,

```
var utcDate = 1470621520;
var localDate = new Date(utcDate);
console.log(localDate);
```

This will automatically take care of the UTC to local time zone conversion.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. What I mean is I want to convert a UTC timestamp (received from the server) to local time timestamp for display.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I actually do it. I have a datepicker that gives me a date like this: 27 February, 2020 (sDate) and a timepicker that gives me time like this: 16:15 (sTime). I want to save this in unixtime as sUnixtime then later retrieve sUnixtime and convert back to nDate and nTime to replicate the same visual design. Here's the code:

To save:

```
sEvent   = sDate + ' ' + sTime;
date_obj = new Date(sEvent);
sUnixtime = Date.parse(date_obj)/1000;
```

To convert back

```
let nUnixtime = new Date(sUnixtime * 1000);
let unixmonth = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"][nUnixtime.getMonth()];
let nDate     = nUnixtime.getDate() + ' ' + unixmonth + ', '+ nUnixtime.getFullYear();
let nTime     = nUnixtime.getHours() +':'+ nUnixtime.getMinutes();
console.log(nDate, 'time',nTime);
```